# javascript multidimensional array is valid

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, isset

I have an array that looks kind of like this `memory[indexGroup][indexItem]`. How can I check if that is valid, in other words if it would work when using `console.log` and getting a value back, not `null`, `undefined` or other non values. Empty, `0` and false are valid. These don't give errors.

This is what I ended up with (seems to work) but it's a mess:

```
function hasMemory() {
    if( typeof memory === 'undefined') return;
    if( typeof memory[indexGroup] === 'undefined') return;
    if( memory[indexGroup] === null ) return;
    if( typeof memory[indexGroup][indexItem] === 'undefined') return;
    if( memory[indexGroup][indexItem] === null) return;
    if( memory[indexGroup][indexItem] !== true ) return;
    return true;
}
```

#### Scenarios

- `memory` is not set
- `memory[indexGroup]` is not set
- `memory[indexGroup][indexItem]` is not set

Then it should just return but if the full multidimensional array is valid, it should return true.

Is there a shorter/better/safer ways to check this?

Comment: `function hasMemory(){ return Boolean(memory && memory[indexGroup] && memory[indexGroup][indexItem]) }`

Comment: @Thomas If this works, maybe add it as an answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function hasMemory() {
return memory && memory[indexGroup] && memory[indexGroup][indexItem]
}
```

To handle the case where memory[indexGroup][indexItem] is 0 or false, based on

```
undefined == null
null == undefined
```

you can add to condition `memory[indexGroup][indexItem]!=null`

Comment: So it checks if these values are... what? Valid values?

Comment: This would check if `undefined`, `null`, `0` or `empty string`. So the logic will break down if you need to accept something other than `undefined/null`

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where `memory[indexGroup][indexItem]` is `0` or `false`. Also, there's no reason to return `true` or `false`. It's functionally equivalent to doing `return (true) ? true : false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for both `null` and `undefined` simultaneously by performing a loose check against `null` but will not work for `0` or `false`.

```js
var u = undefined;
var n = null;
var z = 0;
var f = false;
console.log(u == null);
console.log(n == null);
console.log(z == null);
console.log(f == null);
```

Using that, here's a shorter way of approaching this:

```
function hasMemory() {
  return memory &&
         memory[indexGroup] != null &&
         memory[indexGroup][indexItem] != null;
}
```